# HMAC C# and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, hmac, cryptojs

Having trouble getting C# and Javascript to generate the same HMAC:

C#:

```
string data = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", APPId, requestHttpMethod, requestUri, requestTimeStamp, nonce, requestContentBase64String);

        var secretKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sharedKey);

        byte[] signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyBytes))
        {
            byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(signature);                
            return (incomingBase64Signature.Equals(Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes), StringComparison.Ordinal));
        }
```

Produces: apZUyGrS23BcEd2q5guGS4uQWVvcCvaDXIjCrLn/Hp4=

Javascript:

```
var signatureRawData = "".concat(appId, requestHttpMethod, requestUri, requestTimeStamp, nonce, requestContentBase64String);

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signatureRawData, apiKey);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
```

Produces: mFZyyKT03OOThRnt/9dG/0x+jRde3jCMvI6Rd0eKhEE=

Comment: Where is he apiKey in the c# code?   Is it sharedKey?  Is sercretKeyBytes a string, char[], or byte[]? I suspect secrtetKeyBytes is being converted to a string which is the cause of the issue.

Comment: Sorry, yes, its sharedKey. No, secretKeyBytes is definitely still bytes in the HMCSHA256 object.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer? They key was a string in the javascript.

Comment: Since you have an answer now which simply guesses the solution, you might want to either edit your question to include the missing code so that the answer makes sense or simply delete the question (I don't see any value for future readers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the apiKey in the c# code? Is it sharedKey? Is sercretKeyBytes a string, char[], or byte[]? I suspect secrtetKeyBytes is being converted to a string which is the cause of the issue.