# HMAC - C# and JavaScript give different result

Tags: javascript, c#, security, hmac

My question is similar to [HMAC C# and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412535/hmac-c-sharp-and-javascript), but because question lack some details and answer is not very helpfull I'm asking it again but with more details.

I've implemented HMAC based security that is based on [this tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/).

I have working C# app that can create correct header (I've set static timestamp and nonce on purpose - just for tests):

```
private string CreateHeader(string url)
{
    string appId = "test";
    string apiKey = "A93reRTUJHsCuQSHR+L3GxqOJyDmQpCgps102ciuabc=";

    string requestTimeStamp = "1521622403";
    string nonce = "715de35a4bfd4912baaa16daef21992d";

    url = Uri.EscapeUriString(url.ToLower());

    string signatureRawData = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", appId, url, requestTimeStamp, nonce);

    byte[]secretKeyByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(apiKey);
    byte[] signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureRawData);

    using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyByteArray))
    {
        byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(signature);
        string requestSignatureBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", appId, requestSignatureBase64String, nonce, requestTimeStamp);
    }
}
```

this calculates this header: `test:fhqxcZll+3ZRQi3vRexbNyoT00Yqdoyq3CrAdGQ+4kE=:715de35a4bfd4912baaa16daef21992d:1521622403`

not I'm trying to create Postman pre-request script that will generate same header. Here is my script:

```
function getAuthHeader(httpMethod, requestUrl, requestBody) {
    var CLIENT_KEY = 'test';
    var SECRET_KEY = 'A93reRTUJHsCuQSHR+L3GxqOJyDmQpCgps102ciuabc=';

    var requestTimeStamp = "1521622403";
    var nonce  = "715de35a4bfd4912baaa16daef21992d"
    requestUrl = requestUrl.toLowerCase();

    var signatureRawData = CLIENT_KEY+requestUrl+requestTimeStamp+nonce;
    console.log("signatureRawData: "+signatureRawData);

    var x = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(SECRET_KEY);

    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signatureRawData, x);
    var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

    var header = [CLIENT_KEY, hashInBase64, nonce, requestTimeStamp].join(":");
    console.log("header: "+ header);

    return header;
}

postman.setEnvironmentVariable('hmacAuthHeader', getAuthHeader(request['method'], request['url'], request['data']));
```

but I get different header value:
`test:2ITrhVxr1/4BOxNVNcECnaSh0cW36LiMZWVQ0DaFncY=:715de35a4bfd4912baaa16daef21992d:1521622403`

inside C# I'm converting key and data to hash to `byte[]`, probably this is the problem. How can I do same thing in JavaScript?
C# requires `byte[]` as arguments in `HMACSHA256` and `ComputeHash`.

I'm looking for a way to generate same HMACSHA256 from C# and JavaScript (Postman pre-request script)

Comment: And what is target `url` for which you get given output?

Comment: Also in javascript you do `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(SECRET_KEY);`, which assumes secret key is UTF-8 string (which it is not), while in C# you correctly do `Convert.FromBase64String(apiKey)`. In C# you also do `Uri.EscapeUriString` for some reason, but in javascript you don't (via `encodeURI` or similar).

Comment: @Evk sorry for not specifying that param - `http://localhost:63564/test/secure`

Comment: @Evk I think I have solution. In C# I use `FromBase64String` on key, but I'm not doing that in JavaScript. Adding `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(SECRET_KEY);` in JS seems to solve the problem. I'll checj tjat and post answer if it will work.

Comment: Isn't that what I said in the comment above? :)

Comment: @Evk sorry, I didn't saw that comment. Yes, that's right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to correct hash in JS was the key. In C# I'm calling:

```
byte[]secretKeyByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(apiKey);
```

before I use that key, In JS I was passing raw base64 encoded value.

Here is corrected pre-request script:

```
function S4() {
    return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1); 
}

function GetNonce() {
    return (S4() + S4() + S4()+ S4() + S4() + S4() + S4()+ S4()).toLowerCase();
}

function GetTimeStamp() {
    var d = new Date();
    return Math.round(d.getTime() / 1000);
}

function getAuthHeader(httpMethod, requestUrl, requestBody) {
    var CLIENT_KEY = postman.getEnvironmentVariable('api_user');
    var SECRET_KEY = postman.getEnvironmentVariable('api_key');
    var AUTH_TYPE = 'HMAC';

    var requestTimeStamp = GetTimeStamp();
    var nonce = GetNonce();
    requestUrl = requestUrl.toLowerCase();

    var signatureRawData = [CLIENT_KEY,requestUrl,requestTimeStamp,nonce].join("");
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(SECRET_KEY);

    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signatureRawData, key);
    var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

    var header = [CLIENT_KEY, hashInBase64, nonce, requestTimeStamp].join(":");
    console.log("header: "+ header);

    return AUTH_TYPE+" "+header;
}

postman.setEnvironmentVariable('hmacAuthHeader', getAuthHeader(request['method'], request['url'], request['data']));
```

While I was searching for solution I found nice list of hmac sha256 implementations in many languages: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/

Comment: I am doing the same stuff but im still getting different hash?? any help

Comment: maybe you have a differently encoded key? not sure what might be wrong.